# How can i link a custom library with Cmake?

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, cmake-language, cmake-custom-command

im new in Cmake, im trying to link a library to a project using Cmake, the following code is this:

code of the header:

my_library.h

```
    #ifndef MY_LIBRARY
    #define MY_LIBRARY

    int get_random_number();

    #endif
```

implementation of the header:
my_library.cpp

```
    #include "my_library.h"

    int get_random_number(){

            return 46;
    }
```

Configuration of Cmake

CmakeLists.txt

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

    file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES LIST_DIRECTORIES true *.h *.cpp)

    set(SOURCES ${SOURCES})

    add_library(my_library SHARED ${SOURCES})

    target_include_directories(my_library PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
```

outside the folder i have this:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "my_library.h"
```

```
    int main(){

            std::cout<<"Hello, jairo"<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"A random number is: "<<get_random_number()<<std::endl;

            return 0;

    }
```

CmakeListst.txt

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)

    project(Hello CXX)

    add_subdirectory(my_library)

    add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC my_library)
```

the structure of the whole project is this:

all goes well until y try to execute the Hello.exe file that is generated, windows gives an error saying "Code execution cannot continue because libmy_library.dll was not found" which i undestand as CMake is not linking correctly the library

the structure of the project is this

- main.cpp
- CmakeLists.txt
- -my_library(folder)
- ---my_library.h(inside the folder)
- ---my_library.cpp(inside the folder)
- ---CmakeLists.txt(inside the folder)

im using mingw as compiler and executing all comands with cmd of windows

i have tryed everything, uninstall and install again cmake, adding the target_include_directories but it doesnt work

Comment: ***"Code execution cannot continue because libmy_library.dll was not found" which i undestand as CMake is not linking correctly the library*** No you understood wrong. Its not a linking problem it's a runtime problem. You have to put the dll in the same folder of the executable or help your OS using one of the techniques described in the OS documentation.

Comment: The link to the msdn article about how your OS finds dlls is here: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications)

Comment: i just following this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFSJcdYZcvo&t=1s
How can i do that automatically with Cmake?

Comment: The duplicate link shows you several ways.